# Using `alias' to add a default option - e.g. `alias cd="cd -P" '

Tags: bash, command-line, alias, default-value

I've often been tempted with the idea of using an alias to modify the default behavior of a command line tool.  For example, I often want to resolve the actual path after following a symlink (and have never wanted to maintain the symlink path), so I was thinking about adding something to my .bash_profile file, to make this the default behavior, e.g.:

```
alias cd="cd -P"
```

Is this bad or dangerous for any reason?  If not for this example, is it a bad idea in general?  It makes me feel a little dirty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very common technique.  Here are some common examples.

```
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias make='make -j20'
```

If later you want to run without the alias you can \ the first letter or put the command in quotes, as in

```
\ls
"ls"
```

Answer (score 1):

On every *NIX system I always use `alias cd..='cd ..'`

I say if it helps you in the long run there's no need to feel dirty - computers are supposed to do what we tell them to do, not the other way round..